# No respeta salto de linea en escritura de ficheros Java

Tags: java

!Buenas!

Tengo un problema a la hora de escribir un fichero **.txt** en Java, el cual no me respeta los saltos de linea.

Tengo este método `toString`:

```
public String mostrarCoches() {

    return "Marca: " + marca + "\nModelo: " + modelo + "\nColor: " + color +
            "\nMatricula: " + matricula + "\nKilometros: " + kilometros + "\n---";

}
```

Y este otro para guardar dicho texto en un documento:

```
public void escribirDocumento() {

    try {

        FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Daniel/Downloads/ListaCoches.txt",true);

        for(int i=0; i < mostrarCoches().length(); i++) {

            escribir.write(mostrarCoches().charAt(i));

        }

        escribir.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("El archivo no existe.");
    }
}
```

Lo cual me lo genera de esta forma:

```
Marca: Seat
Modelo: Ibiza
Color: Azul
Matricula: 1234567L
Kilometros: 150000
---Marca: Hyundai
Modelo: Matriz
Color: Gris
Matricula: 7865469H
Kilometros: 250000
```

Y me gustaría que los guiones aparecieran justo debajo, para separar la información de un coche a otro. **¿Como seria?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si que te está respetando los saltos de línea, pero te falta introducir un salto de línea entre cada coche.

Dado que no nos muestras como vas iterando entre varios, sugiero que simplemente agregues un salto de línea al final de los 3 guiones, de manera que cuando llegue el siguiente coche, ya está el salto de línea que necesitas. Tener un salto de línea adicional después del último coche, tampoco creo que sea perjudicial.

Muchas palabras y poco código:

Cambia esto:

```
return "Marca: " + marca + "\nModelo: " + modelo + "\nColor: " + color +
            "\nMatricula: " + matricula + "\nKilometros: " + kilometros + "\n---";
```

Por esto:

```
return "Marca: " + marca + "\nModelo: " + modelo + "\nColor: " + color +
            "\nMatricula: " + matricula + "\nKilometros: " + kilometros + "\n---\n";
```